# An elephant and a lion are currently 1 mile apart. The elephant runs directly away from the lio

Tags: algebra-precalculus

An elephant and a lion are currently $1$ mile apart. The elephant runs directly away from the lion at $19$ miles per hour, while the lion runs directly towards the elephant at $24$ miles per hour. How many minutes will it take for the lion to catch the elephant?

Comment: HINT: The lion is closing the gap at a rate of $24-19=5$ mph.

Answer (score 4):

Let the lion catch the element after $t$ hours. This means the elephant would have travelled a distance of $19t$ miles, while the lion would have travelled a distance of $24t$ miles.

[image]

The distance travelled by the lion must be $1$ mile greater than the distance travelled by the elephant. Hence, we have
$$24t=1+19t \implies t = \dfrac15 \text{ hours} \implies t = 12\text{ minutes}$$

Answer (score 0):

Every hour, the lion runs 24 miles while the elephant runs 19. Thus, the distance between the two animals closes at a rate of 5 miles every hour. The lion catches the elephant after this distance has closed 1 mile, which takes $\frac{1}{5}$ hours to do, or $\frac{1}{5}\cdot 60 = \boxed{12}$ minutes.